# Rotate image element to by +45 degrees

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a an image element to rotate +45 degrees every time user clicks on the rotate button. and this is what I wrote:

```
var gag =  0;

$(objName).click(function () {
   $('.rotate_handle').click(function(){
      var out = gag = gag + 45;
     $('.selektume').rotate(out+'deg');
});

return false;
```

but it is not working.. and I am not very good at debugging so I don't know what is really happening.

Comment: First things first: stop escaping those quote marks. Second: why do you have a `click` handler inside another `click` handler?

Comment: You are not closing your wrapping function properly. Balance your brackets.

Comment: Why are you attaching a click handler from a click handler? Is that intentional?

Comment: @mblase75 the first click handler is for this:

$("p", this).show();
@(this).addClass("selektume");

But I didnt post it here because I just wanted to post what I needed.. not all the code! its like this when a user clicks the image (first click) then the p shows up. then in the <p> I have added 3 images one of them is for rotating then when a user clicks it (second click) then it rotates the other image

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a plugin to provide the `.rotate()` method? I found [jqueryrotate](http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/) but it doesn't want "deg" added to the argument:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7UJxU/)

```
var gag = 0;
$('.rotate_handle').click(function() {
    gag += 45;
    $('.selektume').rotate(gag);
    return false;
});
```

If you're doing it with CSS3, you need to use the `css()` method instead:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7UJxU/1/)

```
var gag = 0;
$('.rotate_handle').click(function() {
    gag += 45;
    $('.selektume').css({
        '-webkit-transform': 'rotate('+gag+'deg)',
        '-moz-transform': 'rotate('+gag+'deg)'
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: @IgorIvanovski Then you need to tell us which one.

Comment: I have tried this before but there is a problem with IE.. I think there is something like ms-transform for IE but it doesnt work on IE8 I guess..

Comment: here it is: http://www.zachstronaut.com/posts/2009/08/07/jquery-animate-css-rotate-scale.html

Comment: Nope, IE8 doesn't support CSS3 rotations. Your plugin's page even says so right at the top. If that was your entire problem, it would have been nice to mention that at the outset.

Comment: hmm I havent tried in IE8 but its ok, the problem is that its not rotating +45 degrees.. here you can see the project: http://www.arbamedia.com/test

Comment: @IgorIvanovski I only understand English, and have no idea how to use that page. Sorry.

Comment: go to the Dyer dhe Dritare in the left menu then you will see 2 images you can drag them and then you will see 3 options under that image, the second one is for rotating

Answer (score 0):

```
var gag =  0;
$('.rotate_handle').click(function(){
     gag = gag + 45;
     $('.selektume').rotate(gag+'deg');
     return false;
});
```

Should do the job, assuming that's all wrapped in a document.ready handler.

Comment: I tried this but its not working, in my console when I first click it it rotates 45deg then 135deg, then 270deg... Its not right!

Comment: You'll have to show more code in that case. It sounds as if the function is being called multiple times, or is being bound more than once. (45 = 1x45, 135-45 = 2x45, 270-135 = 3x45 etc.) It's as if every click binds the handle an extra time, so the rotations multiply up.

Comment: yeah @Rich Bradshaw you are right, here you can see the entire code: http://arbamedia.com/test